# Centos7 server that has no IPV6 assigned to it, can't read IPV6 ips in access log

Tags: nginx, centos7, ipv6, ipv4

I'm using CentOS7, nginx as a reverse proxy and apache web server. This server doesn't have IPv6 assigned to it, therefore there is no IPV6 in the NIC. This server hosts several websites.

When I check the access log, if a visitor has IPV6-only IP, I would only see my server's internal NIC IP instead of the actual visitor's IPv6. If a visitor has an IPv4 IP, I would see the visitor's IPv4.

I can assume that if my server doesn't have IPv6 assigned to it, it can only see IPv4 addresses, and if the visitor has IPvV6 IP I can't read it correctly.

My question is, is this supposed to happen or am I missing something? I can't find the most correct and accurate answer for my question.

Comment: You may be misinterpreting what you see. If your server as no IPv6 assigned, IPv6 packets will not be routed to it.

Comment: Actually, when there is someone trying to access with IPV6, i'm seeing the server's internal IP. I've checked with one visitor which had ipv6 only network.

Comment: Then you must have IPv6 connectivity to your server and the premise of your question is incorrect.

Comment: The server is hosted in google cloud. They don't have the option to just add an ipv6 nic on premise.
Could it be that there is an option for IPV6 only networks to access the server but the webserver can't read the real IP?

Comment: Did you assign IPv6 address in reverse proxy and apache server? Did your server is really available in IPv6? You can test it here: [https://validador.ipv6.br/index.php?lang=en](https://validador.ipv6.br/index.php?lang=en)